# Handle missing value error and proceed with if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, error-handling

I have an IF statement that encompasses multiple else if, how should I do if I want the code to continue running despite having the error:

Warning: Error in eval: argument is missing, with no default [No stack trace available]

--> that is the argument has not been put in input

```
legindex<- (
if(leg2price==""){return("Leg 1:")}
else if (leg3price==""){return(c("Leg 1:","Leg 2:"))}
else if (leg4price==""){return(c("Leg 1:","Leg 2:","Leg 3:"))}
else {return(c("Leg 1:","Leg 2:","Leg 3:","Leg 4:"))})
```

In other words, if I get the error while checking `if(leg2price=="")` I want to go to the next condition `if(leg3price=="")` etc.
If any conditions can be executed then the final vector would be returned.

Comment: Is this called from within a function? Typically you would check for missingness with `is.na()` or with `missing()` if inside a function.

Comment: @jpiversen No it is not coming from a function, actually the inputs come from Shiny app but including that part in the question would have made the topic more complex that it actually is. I already tried `missing(leg2price)==TRUE` and `is.na(leg2price)`, however they are not working

Comment: What sort of input controls are `leg2price` and the like coming from? Usually there is a default value, such as `""`, so it shouldn't be missing. In shiny you could also check out `req()` to wait for some inputs to be filled before doing your calculations.